# Subclass EarlyStopper in scikit-optimize

Tags: python, callback, subclassing, python-class, scikit-optimize

I can't figure out how to subclass EarlyStopper to use it as callback in scikit-optimize (gp_minimize). Based on the documentation. How should I think when subclassinging?

Documentation: https://scikit-optimize.github.io/stable/modules/generated/skopt.callbacks.EarlyStopper.html#skopt.callbacks.EarlyStopper

This article provides an example:
https://medium.com/sitechassethealthcenter/gaussian-process-to-optimize-hyperparameters-of-an-algorithm-5b4810277527

```
from skopt.callbacks import EarlyStopper
class StoppingCriterion(EarlyStopper):
  def __init__(self, delta=0.05, n_best=10):
    super(EarlyStopper, self).__init__()
    self.delta = delta
    self.n_best = n_best
def _criterion(self, result):
  if len(result.func_vals) >= self.n_best:
    func_vals = np.sort(result.func_vals)
    worst = func_vals[self.n_best - 1]
    best = func_vals[0]
    return abs((best - worst)/worst) < self.delta
else:
    return None
```

However, the above throws back an error.

I've also tried this:

```
class MyEarlyStopper(EarlyStopper):
    def __init__(self, patience=15, relative_improvement=0.01):
        super().__init__(patience=patience, relative_improvement=relative_improvement)
        self.best_loss = float("inf")
    
    def __call__(self, result):
        current_loss = result.fun  # current loss value
        if current_loss < self.best_loss * (1 - self.relative_improvement):
            # update the best loss and reset the patience counter
            self.best_loss = current_loss
            self.counter = 0
        else:
            # increment the patience counter
            self.counter += 1
        return self.counter >= self.patience
```

This returns:

```
TypeError: object.__init__() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)
```